# Two agents are missing from the presentation

Tags: anylogic

I have 9 trench agents in my model. When I run the model, I can see that 9 agents are created but I have only 7 agents in the 2D, and 3D presentation. I tried different numbers, and two agents are always missing from the presentation.

Agents are located in a node which has exactly 9 attractors. Please see the pic. [image]

Can Anyone help me to resolve this issue? Thank you.

The problem is I can see that presentation change after a while! Is this usually happen in AnyLogic? Please see the Pic.
[image]

Comment: I notice that I cannot see two of the trenches when the model start. After the first round of excavation, the trenches under excavation move to the place of missing  trenches. Why this is happening? 

Looks like they were located on top of other trenches!!! Trench agents change their location, but they should stay where they are. There is no code or function in the model that make these movements.

Answer (score 1):

Nodes are not used "exclusively", i.e. they do not have a build-in "I am full, no more agents here" capability. They simply define possible agent animation locations.

So in your case, 2 agents are on top of other agents at the same node.

You would need to make those nodes agents themselves with a given capacity. There are many ways to do it (none totally easy), depends on your model setup and what you try to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @Benjamin. Yes, you are right. I have created a node with attractors. I had the same problem even when the number of attractors were more than the agents. ~Since agents were moving after a while, I tried to find out about the place that I made them able to do so. I had Enter block in the model and I changed "new location" to "Not Specified". After the Enter block I had a delay block. So I disabled "restore agent location on exit". So the problem solved. :) :)